# Fit text area to text in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, fonts

When I start typing text randomly somewhere on an artboard in Illustrator, the right side of the text area doesn't line up with the right side of the last symbol.

[image]

In the above image, the tail of the 'W' lines up nicely, but the tail of the 'M' doesn't. Is it possible to shrink the text area to align with the end of the text?

Answer (score 1):

Fonts can have *built in* spacing around the glyph box. You can't generally alter that *inherent* spacing.

*However*, you've got **letter spacing** set to `250`. Letter spacing is applied as part of the *preceding* character and *before* the next glyph. The "character" is comprised of `glyph + kerning + letter spacing`. In your image the letter space setting is also applied to the `m` since it's the base glyph, adding the `250` space after it.

For the image shown in the question, merely selecting the `m` and setting its letter spacing to zero may work.

In general, you *can't* make the area type box *smaller* than the type settings. It *is* possible to sort of "hack" it by making the letter spacing for the last glyph a *negative* value.

Comment: Thanks! That means that a large textbox drawn by hand and centering the text  won't work either right?

Comment: Centering text can be an odd thing for Adobe. *Sometimes* that additional space on the left counts toward centering, and *sometimes* it doesn't. Most often for a single line fo text, the space isn't factored when centering, but for multiple lines of text it probably will be.

Answer (score 0):

Note sure why you would want to do this or why it would matter, but it is possible to shrink the text box manually.

Select the text box and do *Type > Convert to Area Type*, then you can click and drag the text box edge as near to the edge of the text as you dare.

Example

[image]

Comment: It matters because I want to center the text box element to other elements on the artboard. I'll try this trick though, thanks